# Karma Jasmine PhantomeJS test failing ramdomly

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a really strange behavior in my test for a simple angularJS app

Setup: 
Karma v0.10.9 
PhantomJS 1.9.7

**All test passing the first time** ( sometimes the second or third too :-) ) But after a while test failing **randomly**

There are two kinds of errors

```
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'errorForStack.stack')
        at workFn (<my_path>/angular-mocks.js:1811)
```

and

```
Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 
//Line $window.openDatabase('myDB', "", 'Offline DB', 5 * 1024 * 1024);
```

Problem occurs on Windows and Linux

Current fix -> restart Karma --> But i hate this solution since continuous testing is just great

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Sounds like a async problem. Do you mock `openDatabase` in you tests?

Comment: nope not mocked yet , will test it tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the first problem ( Bug in angular-mocks.js ).

Second problem fixed by mocking openDatabase.

Thx for the help